# Where webpack.mix.js location is related to Laravel?

Tags: laravel, npm

After a fresh Laravel install, I created a new project, and ran composer and npm.

Where should a look for `webpack.mix.js`?

After running `npm run dev` it gives me an error in a specific scss file from my project.

I want to remove that file and add new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in the root folder of your project, look at the laravel repo [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel).

Comment: For anyone in the past few months wondering where the mix file went, know that it's been replaced by Vite: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix